# Correct way to implement automatic oauth SSO with marketplace app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have an app developed with PHP for the google marketplace. It is working well although users when installed the app on the domain, it still asks for permissions to access contacts,drive etc when coming from the google default navigation button.

according to google it should be automatic when installing the app on the domain and users should not be prompted for anymore permissions. How is the correct way to implement this using the new SDK and oauth 2.0?

Best regards,
Joao Garin

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post - [SSO with Oauth2.0 for Enterprice Google App (OpenId to Oauth2.0 migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903562/sso-with-oauth2-0-for-enterprice-google-app-openid-to-oauth2-0-migration)

That one is Python oriented but should work with similar ideas on PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your information. From what I get the default universal navigation should be coming with a "code" parameter?
I don't have a "code" parameter to use when coming from universal navigation so that I can skip authorization for users.

Best regards,
Joao Garin

Answer (score 1):

Put all your scope in admin sdk and when user gets redirected to your url "http://www.example.com/?domain=somedomain.com" just redirect the user to google again with only scope="email+profile", "include_granted_scopes=true" makes it include all the scopes you have defined in the admin sdk and try to avoid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope in the request as it will causes confirmation popup for access to users' circles for each user and its broke the seamless domain-wide sso.

**Here is an example in vb.net:**

```
sub page_load
  Dim loginUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=" & _
            "email+profile&" & _
            "state=" & xState & "&" & _
            "redirect_uri=" & GoogleApiCredentialHelper.RedirectUri & "&" & _
            "response_type=code&" & _
            "client_id=" & GoogleApiCredentialHelper.ClientId & "&" & _
            "access_type=offline&" & _
            "approval_prompt=auto&" & _
            "include_granted_scopes=true"

response.redirect(loginUrl)
end sub
```