# SSO with Oauth2.0 for Enterprice Google App (OpenId to Oauth2.0 migration)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Hey I need help in migrating from OpenId based Google App to Oauth2.0 based app.
All that I need is user's email & his profile information.
Currently with these scopes' (email & profile), every user in Google Apps account has to authenticate to access my app.

In short, how do I enable SSO support to access just email & his profile info?
And I don't want to ask each user for the first time before entering to my app.

I am currently using the google python library oauth2client.
Should I use Service Account for this?

Update: https://github.com/Aplopio/django_gapps_oauth2_login should help in setting up SSO with Oauth2.0 for Enterprice Google App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need Service Account for SSO itself. You can do SSO with just regular OAuth. The Apps Marketplace install whitelists your ClientID for the whole domain by the admin and the domain users should not get prompted.

Here is some code I pulled together without any library dependency - https://github.com/entaq/OAuth2Flows

Comment: I did something similar to your comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20687838/1256976 But How should this link (coming for example from the universal navigation) be handled on the server so that any domain user does not get prompted for the authorization? We don't have a code parameter that could be used to avoid asking the user!!

Comment: Or is it like the whitelists doesn't occur for Test Install Flow domain users?

Comment: https://github.com/Aplopio/django_gapps_oauth2_login should help in setting up SSO with Oauth2.0 for Enterprice Google App